# What to fill into ServerUris property for Windows UWP vpn profile

Tags: windows, uwp, vpn

Microsoft official UWP vpn sample: UwpVpnPluginSample, in CreateAppProfile() part function as bellow.

```
// Hard coding parameters for the profile
            VpnPlugInProfile profile = new VpnPlugInProfile();
            ...

            **profile.ServerUris.Add(new Uri("http://10.137.192.135"));**
            var returnedStatus = await agent.AddProfileFromObjectAsync(profile);
            ...
```

I don't kown what url to fill into "ServerUris" property, and what content should be provide in that url.

And :

```
var connectStatus = await agent.ConnectProfileAsync(pluginProfile);
```

the connectStatus always return Other or CannotFindProfile.

Comment: Based on the document-[VpnPlugInProfile.ServerUris Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.vpn.vpnpluginprofile.serveruris?view=winrt-22000#windows-networking-vpn-vpnpluginprofile-serveruris). You need to add your own server URIs to this.

Comment: Yes, I had tried build a server with response of the Plug-in profile (as the Plug-in profile example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/vpnv2-profile-xsd), but still response Other.  
And I don't know how to fill in: <ServerUrlList>testserver1.contoso.com;testserver2.contoso..com</ServerUrlList>

Is it should fill in with the vpn server's address, if so where to put the port?

Comment: That's your server URL, not something like contoso.com